# Conference room avibility app. How to handle reserved dates in the database(Hibernate, H2)

Tags: java, spring, rest, h2

I'm trying to build REST API service that would allow users to reserve conference rooms:
I have two entities in the database(projects requirement):

```
USER
   -  id_user LONG
   - name: text, max. length 50, required
   - surname: text, max. length 100, required
   - login: text, max. length 100, required, unique (allows to identify user)
   - password: text, max. length 100, min. length 6, required
```

```
ROOM
-id_room LONG
-room name: text, max. length 50, required, unique (allows to identify room)
- location description: text, max. length 256, optional
- number of seats: number, max. 100, required
- projector: yes/no, optional, default: no
- phone number: text, max. length 100, optional
```

And I have to be able to book rooms via API call to selected date and time frames. And later return JSON file with a schedule for all rooms or single room or single user.

My solution is to create third table, and add a record every time a users reserves room:

```
RESERVATIONS_TABLE
- id_reservation
- room_id
- user_id
- start_date
- end_date
```

Is it a good choice and what datatype (In Entities) should I use?
It will work in SpringBoot MVC app with H2 database and Hibernate

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: At the moment I've just tried to write model classes. So not much to be honest. The main question is how do I represent the time when room is reserved

Answer (score 1):

Timestamp (long, millisecond) can be used for start_date and end_date. The timestamp value is generic in format and supported for different representations in most of the platforms and programming languages.

Comment: Why people still use legacy, defective by design, and buggy `java.sql.Timestamp` when Java 8, JDBC 4.2, and Hibernate 5 have well-designed and reliable `java.time.LocalDateTime` instead of it?